# sh not found when executing shell command from C++

Tags: c++, shell, path, pipe

I have a function in my C++ program like this:

```
std::string SysExec::executeAndReturnResult(char* cmd) {
    //cout << "[SHELL] : " << cmd << endl;
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe)
        return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while (!feof(pipe)) {
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

When I call it

```
SysExec::executeAndReturnResult("/usr/bin/irsend -d /var/run/lirc/lircd-lirc0 SEND_ONCE Samsung 4");
```

I get this:

```
sh: 4: not found
```

However, if I try to same command from the console, it works fine.

I would like to mention that calling it with a non-numeric argument works with no issue — the following works fine:

```
SysExec::executeAndReturnResult("irsend -d /var/run/lirc/lircd-lirc0 SEND_ONCE Samsung channel+")
```

I have tried Google..but to no avail. Can anyone help me understanding the issue?

//edit on request:

my SysExec.h file looks like this:

```
#include "CompileFlags.h"

/*
 * sysexec.h
 *
 *  Created on: Dec 19, 2012
 *      Author: Shrouk H. Khan / Fingi / root
 */

#ifndef SYSEXEC_H_
#define SYSEXEC_H_
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

namespace fingigcc {

class SysExec {
public:
    SysExec();
    virtual ~SysExec();
    static std::string executeAndReturnResult(char* cmd);
    static int executeAndForget(char* cmd);
    static int execute(char* cmd);
};

} /* namespace fingigcc */
#endif /* SYSEXEC_H_ */
```

And the corresponding cpp file looks like this:

```
/*
 * SysExec.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Dec 19, 2012
 *      Author: Shrouk H. Khan / Fingi / root
 */

#include "../../includes/SysExec.h"
#include "../../includes/Logger.h"

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

namespace fingigcc {

SysExec::SysExec() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

SysExec::~SysExec() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

std::string SysExec::executeAndReturnResult(char* cmd) {
    //cout << "[SHELL] : " << cmd << endl;
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe)
        return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while (!feof(pipe)) {
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}

int SysExec::executeAndForget(char* cmd) {
    //cout << "[SHELL] : " << cmd << endl;
    //do not try to log it..infinite loop..

//  pid_t pid = fork();
//  if (pid < 0) {
//      return -1;
//  } else if (pid == 0) {
//      execl(cmd, (char *) 0);
//  } else {
//
//  }

    system(cmd);

    return 0;
}



}

/* namespace fingigcc */
```

Comment: for running a program, you need a shell, when you want to run a sofware, you get the above error.I think your user to should run your program disabled login shell. `/bin/false` ...

Comment: could you please explain a bit more..

Comment: but it works fine if i do like this: SysExec::executeAndReturnResult("irsend -d /var/run/lirc/lircd-lirc0 SEND_ONCE Samsung channel+")

Comment: i see you use `popen`, this means you want to invoke a shell, `Read from PIPE`,So you need a shell, can you update and put your include files and i test for you?

Comment: Just as clarification from the title of this question, the error you're receiving isn't "`sh` is not found", it's "sh says that `4` is not found". It's treating the last argument of your command, `4`, as an application name.

Comment: Does `irsend` vs `/usr/bin/irsend` make any difference? (Probably not, but there's no harm in checking...)

Comment: @ newfurniturey , yes that is correct. for some reason it is treating numberic arguments as a new application. so i think i cam calling it incorrectly? any suggesiton on how to make this work?

Comment: @ molbdnilo tried that too..no good :(

Comment: i run with my "./data" file as your function parameter, and i got the following result:` root@debian:/home/mohsen/test# ./a.out 
./data: 1: ./data: aaa: not found
./data: 2: ./data: bbbb: not found
./data: 3: ./data: c: not found
./data: 4: ./data: ddddd: not found
./data: 5: ./data: ee: not found
`

Comment: how abut if you try : irsend -d /var/run/lirc/lircd-lirc0 SEND_ONCE Samsung channel+

Comment: `aaa bbb c dddd ee` each  word is one line of my ./data file. by the way , i did chmod 777 ./data

Comment: i don't have your file

Comment: i think your function work correctly ,think a bit more about your parameter.

Comment: Is it significant that it works when you have plain `irsend` and doesn't when you specify `/usr/bin/irsend`?  Have you tried putting `set -x;` immediately in front of the `irsend` command to see what the shell thinks it is executing?  What is the last argument to the `irsend` command; is it the name of a program to be executed?

Comment: yes this function has been working fine for ages! only this numeric paramets make it stop working.